# set shapes name after specialpaste?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I set the shapes name after specialpaste?

Here's my codes.

```
With Sheets("sheet1")
  .Shapes("testpic").Copy
  .PasteSpecial Format:=xlBitmap
End With
```

How to set the new picture's name, as well as location(.top,.left,etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a shape, it has the highest index, so:

```
Sub CopyShape()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")
With ws
    .Shapes("testpic").Copy
    .PasteSpecial Format:=xlBitmap
    With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        .Name = "myName"
        .Top = 100
        'etc.
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Be aware, although @Doug Glancy provides a working answer, if you delete shapes at all the count may not accurately reflect the shapes index number and thus the name will be missed.

Alternately you can after `End With` while the pasted item is still selected  do a `Selection.Name="newShape"`
You will still have define the location, but he has given you the way to get to that.