# VBA Excel Case query with Combobox and shape copying

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make my combobox dropdown list functional.

[image]

where I would like to increment value in the cell +1 in the other sheet and copy the shape from another sheet at once.

I wrote the code like this:

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim picName As String
 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B65")

 picName = "Firestop"

 Select Case rng

 Case "CFS-PL 107"

 Worksheets("hilti firestopping stores").Range("E5").Value = Range("E5") + 1
 Worksheets("hilti firestopping stores").Shapes("Firestop_Plug").Copy
 ActiveSheet.Range("L24").PasteSpecial Name = "Firestop"

 End Select
 End Sub
```

I have got basically 2 problems here:

1. The value in the cell "E5" increases only up to 1. If I select this case egain it remains still 1, whereas it should be 2, as I set the +1 increment.
2. The objects (images) are copied properly, although I would like to set them some unique name, other than "Picture..." which would be next ordered with numeration the same as in the case of "Picture".

The question here:
[How to rename the selected shape in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305334/how-to-rename-the-selected-shape-in-excel)
doesn't solve my problem, because there is no information about the incremented order of the shape id.
I found something similar here:

[set shapes name after specialpaste?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356437/set-shapes-name-after-specialpaste)

And tried to use in my code:

```
 Worksheets("hilti firestopping stores").Shapes("Firestop_Plug").Copy
 ActiveSheet.Range("L24").PasteSpcial
 With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
 .Name = "Firestop"
 End With
```

But I am getting an error:
**

> Compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference

**

[image]
Could anyone advise where the problem might be?

Comment: `Set rng = ...` Or `Dim rng As String`

Comment: ^ well please don't `Dim rng As String`, that's very confusing.

Comment: It works,

Now I updated the query and the problem is, that my value in the target sheet changed only once. Shall I use another code for incrementation +1 for my cell?

Comment: I have changed the query in general. Your advice is fine, but I still have got another 2 problems to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

My code should look like this:

```
 With Sheets("hilti firestopping stores").Range("E5")  'Cell value incrementation by 1
            .Value = .Value + 1       
        End With
    Worksheets("hilti firestopping stores").Shapes("Firestop_Plug").Copy ' copying the shape from another sheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("L24").PasteSpecial   'paste the shape in the target sheet
    Selection.Name = "Firestop"   'instant rename the shape pasted, while is still selected
```

Then I have both issues sorted. At the moment of the Case selection my image comes to the target sheet and value in the mother cell changes automatically.